# Failed to comment: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

Tags: json, wordpress, flutter, api

```
Failed to comment: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1
```

This is the error I am getting while using the following GitHub tutorial:
https://github.com/dreamsoftin/flutter_wordpress/

This happen when I click on 'create comment'

I also get the error:

```
I/flutter (17327): Failed to create post: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
I/flutter (17327): Receiver: null
I/flutter (17327): Tried calling: length
```

When I try to create a post.

Everything works, except for these two. Why is that? I can't find where the error is coming from, it does not give me a way to debug it.

Anyone who can help?

This is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_wordpress/flutter_wordpress.dart' as wp;

import 'post_page.dart';

class PostListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final wp.WordPress wordPress;
  final wp.User user;

  PostListPage({Key key, @required this.wordPress, this.user});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Posts"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: PostsBuilder(
          wordPress: wordPress,
          user: user,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PostsBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  final wp.WordPress wordPress;
  final wp.User user;

  PostsBuilder({Key key, @required this.wordPress, this.user});

  @override
  PostsBuilderState createState() => PostsBuilderState();
}

class PostsBuilderState extends State<PostsBuilder> {
  final paddingCardsList = EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 8.0);
  final padding_4 = EdgeInsets.all(4.0);
  final padding_8 = EdgeInsets.all(8.0);
  final padding_16 = EdgeInsets.all(16.0);

  Future<List<wp.Post>> posts;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    fetchPosts();
  }

  void createPost({@required wp.User user}) {
    final post = widget.wordPress.createPost(
      post: new wp.Post(
        title: 'First post as a Chief Editor',
        content: 'Blah! blah! blah!',
        excerpt: 'Discussion about blah!',
        authorID: user.id,
        commentStatus: wp.PostCommentStatus.open,
        pingStatus: wp.PostPingStatus.closed,
        status: wp.PostPageStatus.publish,
        format: wp.PostFormat.standard,
        sticky: true,
      ),
    );

    post.then((p) {
      print('Post created successfully with ID: ${p.id}');
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Failed to create post: $err');
    });
  }

//  yahya

  Future<void> createUser({@required String email, @required String username, @required String password, @required List<String> roles}) async {
    await widget.wordPress.createUser(
      user: wp.User(
        email: email,
        password: password,
        username: username,
        roles: roles
      )
    ).then((p) {
      print('User created successfully ${p}');
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Failed to create user: $err');
    });
  }

//  =====================
//  UPDATE START
//  =====================

  Future<void> updatePost({@required int id, @required int userId}) async {
    await widget.wordPress.updatePost(
      post: new wp.Post(
        title: 'First post as a Chief Editor',
        content: 'Blah! blah! blah!',
        excerpt: 'Discussion about blah!',
        authorID: userId,
        commentStatus: wp.PostCommentStatus.open,
        pingStatus: wp.PostPingStatus.closed,
        status: wp.PostPageStatus.publish,
        format: wp.PostFormat.standard,
        sticky: true,
      ),
      id: id, //
    ).then((p) {
      print('Post updated successfully with ID ${p}');
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Failed to update post: $err');
    });
  }

  Future<void> updateComment({@required int id, @required int postId, @required wp.User user}) async {
    await widget.wordPress.updateComment(
      comment: new wp.Comment(
        content: "Comment Updated2!",
        author: user.id,
        post: postId,
      ),
      id: id,
    ).then((c) {
      print('Comment updated successfully "$c"');
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Failed to update Comment: $err');
    });
  }

  Future<void> updateUser({@required int id, @required String username, @required String email}) async {
    await widget.wordPress.updateUser(
      user: new wp.User(
        description: "This is description for this user",
        username: username,
        id: id,
        email: email
      ),
      id: id,
    ).then((u) {
      print('User updated successfully $u');
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Failed to update User: $err');
    });
  }

//  =====================
//  UPDATE END
//  =====================

//  =====================
//  DELETE START
//  =====================

  Future<void> deletePost({@required int id}) async {
    await widget.wordPress.deletePost(id: id).then((p) {
      print('Post Deleted successfully: $p');
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Failed to Delete post: $err');
    });
  }

  Future<void> deleteComment({@required int id}) async {
    await widget.wordPress.deleteComment(id: id).then((c) {
      print('Comment Deleted successfully: $c');
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Failed to Delete comment: $err');
    });
  }

  Future<void> deleteUser({@required int id, @required int reassign}) async {
    await widget.wordPress.deleteUser(id: id, reassign: reassign).then((u) {
      print('User Deleted successfully: $u');
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Failed to Delete user: $err');
    });
  }

//  =====================
//  DELETE END
//  =====================

//  end yahya

  void createComment({@required int userId, @required int postId}) {
    final comment = widget.wordPress.createComment(
      comment: new wp.Comment(
        author: userId,
        post: postId,
        content: "First!",
        parent: 0,
      ),
    );

    comment.then((c) {
      print('Comment successfully posted with ID: ${c.id}');
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Failed to comment: $err');
    });
  }

  Future<void> fetchPosts() {
    setState(() {
      posts = widget.wordPress.fetchPosts(
        postParams: wp.ParamsPostList(perPage: 15),
        fetchAuthor: true,
        fetchFeaturedMedia: true,
      );
    });
    return posts;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<wp.Post>>(
      future: posts,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return RefreshIndicator(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                int id = snapshot.data[i].id;
                String title = snapshot.data[i].title.rendered;
                String author = snapshot.data[i].author.name;
                String content = snapshot.data[i].content.rendered;
                wp.Media featuredMedia = snapshot.data[i].featuredMedia;

                return Padding(
                  padding: paddingCardsList,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      openPostPage(snapshot.data[i]);
                    },
                    child: _buildPostCard(
                      author: author,
                      title: title,
                      content: content,
                      featuredMedia: featuredMedia,
                      id : id,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
            ),
            onRefresh: fetchPosts,
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(
            snapshot.error.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
          );
        }

        return CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.blue),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPostCard({
    String author,
    String title,
    String content,
    wp.Media featuredMedia,
    int id,
  }) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 4.0),
            child: Text(
              title,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
            ),
          ),
          _buildFeaturedMedia(featuredMedia),
          featuredMedia == null
              ? Divider()
              : SizedBox(
                  width: 0,
                  height: 0,
                ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 8.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  author,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    createComment(postId: 1, userId: 1);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                  label: Text(
                    "Create New Comment",
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    updateComment(user: widget.user, id: 1, postId: 1);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                  label: Text(
                    "Update Comment with ID #1",
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    deleteComment(id: 1);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                  label: Text(
                    "Delete Comment with ID #1",
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    updatePost(userId: widget.user.id, id: 1);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.white),
                  label: Text(
                    "Update Post with ID #1",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    deletePost(id: 1);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.white),
                  label: Text(
                    "Delete Post with ID #1",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    createPost(user: widget.user);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle, color: Colors.white,),
                  label: Text(
                    "Create New Post",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    createUser(roles: ["subscriber"], username: "myUserName", password: "123", email: "myEmail@domain.com");
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle, color: Colors.white,),
                  label: Text(
                    "Create New User",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    updateUser(id: 1, email: "newuser@gmaill.com", username: "newuser");
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.white,),
                  label: Text(
                    "Update User with ID #1",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    deleteUser(id: 1, reassign: 1);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.white,),
                  label: Text(
                    "Delete User with ID #1",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFeaturedMedia(wp.Media featuredMedia) {
    if (featuredMedia == null) {
      return SizedBox(
        width: 0.0,
        height: 0.0,
      );
    }
    String imgSource = featuredMedia.mediaDetails.sizes.mediumLarge.sourceUrl;
    imgSource = imgSource.replaceAll('localhost', '192.168.6.165');
    return Center(
      child: Image.network(
        imgSource,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  }

  void openPostPage(wp.Post post) {
    print('OnTapped');
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return SinglePostPage(
          wordPress: widget.wordPress,
          post: post,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Related code on different file:

```
 /// This is used to create a [Comment] for a [Post]. Before this method can be called,
  /// [User] writing the comment needs to be authenticated first by calling
  /// [WordPress.authenticateUser]. On success, the [Comment] object is returned containing
  /// comment information.
  ///
  /// In case of an error, a [WordPressError] object is thrown.
  Future<Comment> createComment({required Comment comment}) async {
    final StringBuffer url = new StringBuffer(_baseUrl + URL_COMMENTS);

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url.toString()),
      headers: _urlHeader,
      body: comment.toJson(),
    );

    if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300) {
      return Comment.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      try {
        WordPressError err =
            WordPressError.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
        throw err;
      } catch (e) {
        throw new WordPressError(message: response.body);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is an example of what my snapshot data is giving:

```
Post: { id: 2613, title: Alpha male, author: {id: 3, name: Mike}}
```

And here is e.g. how to create a comment:

```
        ElevatedButton.icon(
          onPressed: () {
            createComment(postId: 1, userId: 1);
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
          label: Text(
            "Create New Comment",
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: maybe here  ***itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0*** your  snapshot.data is null.

Comment: I already tried that, but that did not work sadly :(

Comment: Check snapshot.data != null then return your widget, otherwise return simple text widget with No data string. And if data is null, then check snapshot.error part.

Comment: I used print(snapshot.data); to check it out and it is not empty (because I can see the posts anyway). The problem is when you try to create comments or posts itself... those buttons (when clicked on them) are giving the errors.

It might be an ID issue. It shows for ALL posts the text: "Update comment with ID #1", while obviously every post has a different ID and is not 1.... but then again, creating a post has nothing to do with that and it still does not work.

Comment: See edited post for more details.